# What should I consider if I want to integrate a kind of testing into a build pipeline of a Linux distribution?

Tags: linux, testing, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

If I developed a testing method for compilers and I want to integrate it into a reproductive build pipeline of a popular Linux distribution, what should I consider?

Comment: Do you want to run your tests on a popular Linux distro, or do you want to include your test suite in the upstream Linux distro conformance tests?

Comment: Hi, I think it's the latter. I want to integrate a testing method in the Linux build pipeline, so that every time before a Linux distribution is released it can be tested by this testing method. To achieve this, what should I learn and consider?